# pop-under for onclick, exit and back button press

Tags: javascript

I was creating a pop under which should pop under when a user clicks on a link or closes the browser or clicks back button. I know a little java script so would be really thankful if someone helps me out here. Here is my code for pop up

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com','','width='+screen.width+',height='+screen.height+',location=yes,menubar=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes').blur(); window.focus()">Click me to open pop up</a>
```

here is the actual page I am working on

[http://www.techblogbuzz.com/mypopup/](http://techblogbuzz.com/mypopup)

Comment: What exact is your question? Looks like your code is working ...

Comment: yes, but it does is only pop up, when you click. What i want is it should pop under , when you click as well as when you close browser and press back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `onbeforeunload` event

```
var popup = function(){     
    window.open('http://www.google.com','','width='+screen.width+',height='+screen.height+',location=yes,menubar=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes').blur(); 
    window.focus()
};

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    popup();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/orlando/DjH7r/

btw.. most browsers will block the popup

Comment: Thanks Orlando, I am almost there now everything works as required, but it pops up instead of poping up . I have changes to the code on my page.  http://www.techblogbuzz.com/mypopup/